# limit to geom_path size arguments?

Tags: r, ggplot2

It seems like there is a lower limit to how thin a line can be with `geom_path`

```
m <- ggplot(economics, aes(unemploy/pop, psavert))
m + geom_path(size = 0.05) ## same as below
m + geom_path(size = 0.5)  ## same as above
```

How can I make it thinner than this limit?

Comment: try `geom_path(aes(size = 0.5))`

Comment: Also if you use `geom_line` instead of `geom_path` then you can also adjust the size outside of the aesthetic like you have in your post.

Comment: `aes` arguments are interpreted as `strings`. This just adds a legend with the line labeled as `0.5`

Comment: `geom_line` will act differently than `geom_path`, and also has a lower limit to how thin it can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869337/geom-sf-size-argument-doesnt-work-when-size-1) about not being able to see a small differences in line size when plotting in RStudio.  The answer was that the differences in line size became noticeable once I saved the plot with `ggsave()`.  The limit seemed to be how finely the RStudio graphics device/viewer could display different size lines.

Using your example, I also don't see a noticeable difference in line size when plotting `size = 0.05` and `size = 0.5` in RStudio.  After saving the plot to a pdf with `ggsave()` though, I can see the difference after zooming in a bit.