# geom_sf size argument doesn't work when size < 1

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, r-sf

**Question:** I'm trying to create a map of U.S. states/counties with the sf package and `geom_sf()` from ggplot2, but I can't get the `size` argument for polygon border line width in `geom_sf()` to properly create thin lines when `size < 1` (e.g. `ggplot(sf_obj) %>% geom_sf(size = 0.5)`.

Specifically, the border lines of a state/county appear to have the same width from the arbitrarily small (e.g. `size = 0.05`) all the way up to `size = 0.702`.  Then there seems to be a strange cutoff at `size = 0.702`, above which the border lines abruptly appear wider. Then from `size = 0.703` up to `size = 1` the border lines appear to have the same width.  For `size` > 1, the border lines appear gradually wider, as expected.

**Research:** It does appear that `geom_sf()` supports gradual changes in `size` < 1, as shown in the code for maps by Bob Rudis [here](https://rud.is/b/2017/09/18/mapping-fall-foliage-with-sf/) and Matt Strimas-Mackey [here](http://strimas.com/r/ebird-county/).  It seems like my issue may be the same one referenced [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2275) on ggplot2's Github page titled "geom_sf rounds small sizes up to 1", but the issue was closed and I'm not sure if/how I can implement the fix on my machine. There's another similar-looking issue filed [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2330) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183558/limit-to-geom-path-size-arguments)), but Hadley suggested that the problem in this case may be the graphics device/viewer.  I replicated my issue (and the two Github issues linked above) in RStudio and RGUI, but I'm not sure how else to test/change my graphics device/viewer.

**Version info:** I'm using ggplot2_3.0.0, sf_0.6.3, R version 3.5.1, RStudio version 1.1.456, and Windows 10 version 1803; the issue was also replicated using RGUI.

**Code:** Below is a reprex using the North Carolina map from the `geom_sf()` [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html).  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(reprex))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(sf))

#################################################

# plot north carolina map
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
ggplot(nc) + geom_sf(size = 0.05)
```

[image]

```
nc %>% ggplot() + geom_sf(size = 0.702)
```

[image]

```
nc %>% ggplot() + geom_sf(size = 0.703)
```

[image]

```
# get version info
packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.0.0'
packageVersion("sf")
#> [1] '0.6.3'
version
#>                _                           
#> platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
#> arch           x86_64                      
#> os             mingw32                     
#> system         x86_64, mingw32             
#> status                                     
#> major          3                           
#> minor          5.1                         
#> year           2018                        
#> month          07                          
#> day            02                          
#> svn rev        74947                       
#> language       R                           
#> version.string R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
#> nickname       Feather Spray
```

**UPDATE:** As Chris and Ibusett pointed out, the border lines have the expected width after using `ggsave`.  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did you output using `ggsave`? I can't reproduce the error on my machine.

Comment: I see the same behaviour, but I guess that really depends on the graphics device. For example, if you try saving to pdf using `ggsave` you will have different results. Also, consider that there is a limit on how much "thin" a line can be rendered on your monitor, and that the width of a line on a monitor is inevitably "quantized" (i.e., it can be 1 pixel or 2 pixels, but not 1.5 pixels), so that I think there will always be some "cutoff points" where you see sudden changes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a problem of graphic devices rather than a coding problem and the comments have provided 
a solution as per update of the OP

Answer (score 3):

This answer is just for the people who don't like to `ggsave` all their plots, to provide some tricks.

Yes it does depend on the graphics device. Some graphics devices are pretty bad when it comes to these kinds of things (looking at you, default Windows device). The reprex that follows was executed with chunk options set to render the plot with the 'ragg' package.

```r
#+ setup, include=FALSE
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = "ragg_png")

#+ main
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
p1 <- ggplot(nc) + geom_sf(size = 0.05) + ggtitle("size = 0.05")
p2 <- ggplot(nc) + geom_sf(size = 0.50) + ggtitle("size = 0.50")
p3 <- ggplot(nc) + geom_sf(size = 1.00) + ggtitle("size = 1.00")
p4 <- ggplot(nc) + geom_sf(size = 2.00) + ggtitle("size = 2.00")

p1 + p2 + p3 + p4
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

In markdown files, you can set the default graphics device in a similar way. For setting the device globally for the entire document:

````
```{r, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  dev = "ragg_png"
)
```
````

To those working on RStudio, you can change the default graphics device by going to 'Tools > Global options > General > Graphics (tab)'

[image]